# anonymous types and generics

Tags: c#

I cannot find a way to pass an anonymous type to a generic class as a type parameter.

// this is the class I want to instantiate

```
public class ExtArrayStore<T> : IViewComponent 
{
    public IQueryable<T> Data { get; set; }
```

...
// the creator class

```
public static class ArrayStoreGenerator
{
    public static ExtArrayStore<T> CreateInstance<T>(IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        return new ExtArrayStore<T>();
    }
}
```

// trying to use this

```
IQueryable usersQuery= ((from k in bo.usersselect new { userid = k.userid, k.username}).AsQueryable());
      var x = ArrayStoreGenerator.CreateInstance(usersQuery);
```

I am getting;

The type arguments for method *ArrayStoreGenerator.CreateInstance(System.Linq.IQueryable)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly*

Is there a way to achieve this? ( I am thinking of Interfaces and returning an interface, but not sure if it would work) can any one help with passing anon types to generics.

Comment: Could you provide the implementation of `ArrayStoreGenerator`? I cannot find it with Google so I suspect this is a library of your own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`usersQuery` is being typed as the non-generic `IQueryable` because you explicitly specify that in the variable's declaration.

Instead, do `var usersQuery = ...`. This will type the variable as `IQueryable<TAnon>`, which then matches the signature of `ArrayStoreGenerator.CreateInstance`.

Answer (score 3):

You should define usersQuery as var.

Answer (score 2):

What if you try `var usersQuery` local variable instead of explicitly specify its type?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `ToArray`:

```
var x = ArrayStoreGenerator.CreateInstance(usersQuery.ToArray());
```